# Find and get element from site with Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I need your help, I have a  website and I must get information from this site. Example of the site: [Image HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruBmj.png)
[image]

I must get the data from `class` `inputField`, but I must sort the data, example: if `class` `key` is `Type of Work` we write the data from `class` `inputField` to `var1`, if `class` `key` is `Application No.` we write the data from `class` `inputField` to `var2`, if `class` `key` is `Date Lodged` we write the data from `class` `inputField` to `var3`. 
Code:

```
    import scrapy
    from tasks.items import TasksItem
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


    class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        title = []
        type = []
        name = 'Spider'
        allowed_domains = ['https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/']

        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/TEMP/Scrapy/chromedriver')

        driver.get('https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiryInit.do?docType=5&nodeNum=1118')
        driver.get('https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiry.do?number=&lodgeRangeType=on&dateFrom=01%2F09%2F2017&dateTo=30%2F09%2F2017&detDateFromString=&detDateToString=&streetName=&suburb=0&unitNum=&houseNum=0%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09&planNumber=&strataPlan=&lotNumber=&propertyName=&searchMode=A&submitButton=Search')

        title = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.plain_header')
        type = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('p.rowDataOnly')
        for i in type:
            t1 = i.find_element_by_class_name('key').text
            if t1 == 'Type of Work':
                var1 = t1
            elif t1 == 'some_text':
                var2 = t1
            else:
                var3 = t1
```

But I don't know haw I can get the data from `inputField`

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic is not going to work well. What you want to do is get a count of the number of properties and then loop through each one. As you loop through each one, you grab the three items you are interested in and store them in the three variables (you really should use more descriptive names, btw).

Something like the below should do.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    title = []
    type = []
    name = 'Spider'
    allowed_domains = ['https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/']

    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/TEMP/Scrapy/chromedriver')

    driver.get('https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiryInit.do?docType=5&nodeNum=1118')
    driver.get('https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiry.do?number=&lodgeRangeType=on&dateFrom=01%2F09%2F2017&dateTo=30%2F09%2F2017&detDateFromString=&detDateToString=&streetName=&suburb=0&unitNum=&houseNum=0%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09&planNumber=&strataPlan=&lotNumber=&propertyName=&searchMode=A&submitButton=Search')

    titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.plain_header')
    for i in range(0, len(titles) - 1):
        var1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='key'][.='Type of Work']/following-sibling::span[@class='inputField']")[i].text
        var2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='key'][.='Application No.']/following-sibling::span[@class='inputField']")[i].text
        var3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='key'][.='Date Lodged']/following-sibling::span[@class='inputField']")[i].text
```

To make this easier to maintain (and read), you could take the code in the last three lines and turn it into a function where you pass in the field name, e.g. Date Lodged, and it returns the field value, e.g. 01/09/2017. I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I get    `for i in range(0, titles.count-1):`
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'int'`

Comment: I was using `.count` instead of `len()`... wrong language. try now

Answer (score -1):

I tried in Java. You could use the same approach in python.

You can get all the span elements with **class=key** and  those with **class=inputField**.
Iterate on these and get the interested infos.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiryInit.do?docType=5&nodeNum=1118");
        driver.get("https://ecouncil.bayside.vic.gov.au/eservice/daEnquiry.do?number=&lodgeRangeType=on&dateFrom=01%2F09%2F2017&dateTo=30%2F09%2F2017&detDateFromString=&detDateToString=&streetName=&suburb=0&unitNum=&houseNum=0%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09&planNumber=&strataPlan=&lotNumber=&propertyName=&searchMode=A&submitButton=Search");

        List<WebElement> keys = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='key']"));
        List<WebElement> inputFields = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='inputField']"));

        String var1, var2, var3;

        for (int j = 0; j < keys.size(); j++) {
            WebElement key = keys.get(j);
            System.out.println("key: " + key.getText());
            System.out.println("inputField: " + inputFields.get(j).getText());
            if (key.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Type of Work")) {
                var1 = inputFields.get(j).getText();
                System.out.println("var1: " + var1);
            } else if (key.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Application No.")) {
                var2 = inputFields.get(j).getText();
                System.out.println("var2: " + var2);
            } else if (key.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Date Lodged")) {
                var3 = inputFields.get(j).getText();
                System.out.println("var3: " + var3);
            }

            System.out.println("------------------" + j + "------------------");

        }

    }
```